# Plotting contour maps side by side in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, cartopy

I have two contour maps of precipitation in India for different years that I would like to be able to print in the same function, preferably side by side. I am not sure how to do this.

**Map A** =

```
height = width/1.666

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width,height))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()
ax.gridlines()
ax.set_extent([66, 96, 4, 33])

ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS)

ax.plot(77.2, 28.6, 'ro', markersize=7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.text(77.2, 28.6, '   New Delhi', transform=ccrs.Geodetic())  
ax.plot(72.87, 19.07, 'bo', markersize=7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.text(72.87, 19.07, '   Mumbai', transform=ccrs.Geodetic()) 
ax.plot(77.59, 12.97, 'bo', markersize=7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.text(77.59, 12.97, '   Bangalore', transform=ccrs.Geodetic())  

cs= ax.contourf(lonind, latind, tind1988, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), cmap = 'BuPu')
cbar= plt.colorbar(cs)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel(r"$Rainfall-(mm/day)$",rotation =270, labelpad=20, fontsize=14)

plt.show()
```

**Map B** =

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width,height))

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()
ax.gridlines()
ax.set_extent([66, 96, 4, 33])

ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS)

ax.plot(77.2, 28.6, 'ro', markersize=7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.text(77.2, 28.6, '   New Delhi', transform=ccrs.Geodetic())  
ax.plot(72.87, 19.07, 'bo', markersize=7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.text(72.87, 19.07, '   Mumbai', transform=ccrs.Geodetic()) 
ax.plot(77.59, 12.97, 'bo', markersize=7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.text(77.59, 12.97, '   Bangalore', transform=ccrs.Geodetic()) 

cs= ax.contourf(lonind, latind, tind2018, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), cmap = 'BuPu')
cbar= plt.colorbar(cs)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel(r"$Rainfall-(mm/day)$",rotation =270, labelpad=20, fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

Any suggestions on how I could do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that's needed is to adjust the calls to `add_subplot`:

```py
height = width/1.666

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()
ax.gridlines()
ax.set_extent([66, 96, 4, 33])

ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS)

ax.plot(77.2, 28.6, 'ro', markersize=7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.text(77.2, 28.6, '   New Delhi', transform=ccrs.Geodetic())  
ax.plot(72.87, 19.07, 'bo', markersize=7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.text(72.87, 19.07, '   Mumbai', transform=ccrs.Geodetic()) 
ax.plot(77.59, 12.97, 'bo', markersize=7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.text(77.59, 12.97, '   Bangalore', transform=ccrs.Geodetic())  

cs = ax.contourf(lonind, latind, tind1988, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), cmap='BuPu')
cbar = plt.colorbar(cs)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel(r"$Rainfall-(mm/day)$", rotation=270, labelpad=20, fontsize=14)

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()
ax.gridlines()
ax.set_extent([66, 96, 4, 33])

ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS)

ax.plot(77.2, 28.6, 'ro', markersize=7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.text(77.2, 28.6, '   New Delhi', transform=ccrs.Geodetic())  
ax.plot(72.87, 19.07, 'bo', markersize=7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.text(72.87, 19.07, '   Mumbai', transform=ccrs.Geodetic()) 
ax.plot(77.59, 12.97, 'bo', markersize=7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.text(77.59, 12.97, '   Bangalore', transform=ccrs.Geodetic()) 

cs = ax.contourf(lonind, latind, tind2018, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), cmap = 'BuPu')
cbar = plt.colorbar(cs)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel(r"$Rainfall-(mm/day)$", rotation=270, labelpad=20, fontsize=14)

plt.show()
```

See also [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplot_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-subplot-demo-py) from the matplotlib docs.

Comment: Thank you very much! A quick follow up - how could I change the code so the colourbar only appears once, instead of alongside each map?

Comment: The easy way would be to delete the first call to `colorbar` and leave the second.